# Centralizar Icons no mobile - Css + Html

Tags: css, html5, mobile

Não estou conseguindo centralizar o meus icones no mobile, preciso dessa forcinha, aqui esta o meu codigo abaixo de @media(max-width:700px);

```css
  footer{     bottom:0 ;     position: initial;
      padding: 10px 0;
   height: 78px;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<footer>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/99gourmet"><img src="facebook.png"></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/99gourmetapp/"><img src="instagramLogo.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/99gourmet" ><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://br.pinterest.com/99gourmet" ><img src="pinterest-sign.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centralizar modo 1: (cada um em sua linha)

```css
  footer{     bottom:0 ;     position: initial;
      padding: 10px 0;
   height: 78px;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   text-align:center;
  }

footer li {text-align:center;}


----------
```

```html
<footer>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/99gourmet"><img src="facebook.png"></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/99gourmetapp/"><img src="instagramLogo.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/99gourmet" ><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://br.pinterest.com/99gourmet" ><img src="pinterest-sign.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```

Centralizar modo 2: (Lado a lado, centralizado na tela)

```css
  footer{     bottom:0 ;     position: initial;
      padding: 10px 0;
   height: 78px;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   text-align:center;
  }

footer li {text-align:center; display:inline-flex;}


----------
```

```html
<footer>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/99gourmet"><img src="facebook.png"></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/99gourmetapp/"><img src="instagramLogo.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/99gourmet" ><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="https://br.pinterest.com/99gourmet" ><img src="pinterest-sign.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```